# I can sense that

Tags: idiomatic-language

*I can sense that you think we had more to discuss.*

- Is it perfectly natural to use "sense" here instead of "tell"?

Answer (score 1):

For this native speaker of American English, both are perfectly idiomatic. They do differ slightly in meaning, as to the degree of the speaker’s confidence.

> I **can tell** that you’re angry

suggests that the speaker is highly confident that the person addressed is indeed angry, whereas

> I **can sense** that you’re angry

is somewhat more conjectural. And, by the way, still less certainty is conveyed by

> I **sense** that you’re angry.

Answer (score -1):

In a sense, it depends on what you want to express, and not on idiomatic language. So yes, both look idiomatic, and can be followed by a *that-clause*.

HOWEVER:

I **can tell** ... ( most likely to mean - **ascertain**);

I can sense ... ( it *literally* means I *can* sense; it may bear some metaphorical meaning );

Comment: I think both apply in general. But I think they involve slightly different meanings of how you pick up information. I feel "I can tell that you think we had more to discuss" would often mean "because of the things you said, I can judge what you think", while "I can sense..." suggests another source of information such as their attitude or body language.